# JDBC Connection Pool changes in properties

Tags: java, jdbc, glassfish, connection-pooling

My question is very basic. I am creating a JDBC connection pool in glassfish server and I just want to know if let's say 10 million people will access my website and I have to show them their requirements by fetching data from my database MYSQL so approximately I will fetch data from database 10 million times per day then is there any changes I must do in following properties like Steady Pool Size, Max Pool Size, Pool Resize Quantity or in any other ?? Many thanks[image]

Comment: That is impossible to tell just from the information you provided. The number of connections needed will depend a lot on what your application is doing and how it utilizes connections. You will need to do proper load testing of your application and tune your application accordingly, and of course closely monitor your application during production use.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel ok but can I increase steady pool size to lets say 100 and max pool size to lets say 100, what benefit I may get if I increase ?

Comment: You will need to test that. Having a pool that is too large can also have negative effects on performance, just like a pool that is too small. There is no magic bullet.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel ok please suggest me how can I do proper load testing ? is there any link available or whats the method pls tell me ?